# Android gradient background

Tags: android, xml, gradient

I need to implement something like this, with black gradient effect at the bottom
[image]

I used the below code 
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_custom_drawable"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/dead"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/place_image"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#AA000000">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medeu"
            android:id="@+id/place_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Almaty region"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/place_id"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/place_id_sub"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my_custom_drawable.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="#80000000"
        android:angle="270"
        android:dither="true"
        />
</shape>
```

I end up getting like this

[image: Image 2]

Why am I not getting the effect as first image, I referred several top answers from other questions

Comment: check my answer... i have tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `ImageView` is covering your `RelativeLayout`, which you set the background of, so it is not visible.

Adding a `View` with the desired background above your `ImageView` instead of setting the background of the `RelativeLayout` should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/dead" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_custom_drawable" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Medeu"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_id_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/place_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Almaty region"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="@color/black_transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#555994"
        android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your image is above the gradient.